# dl4j on netbeans without maven

Tags: java, netbeans, deeplearning4j

I have a question
Is there any way to use dl4j on netbeans without maven?
I have many restriction in muy computer, I can't install maven (nothing, by the way, politics of my job, you know...) but I have Netbeans 8.1. 
[I have these libraries in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxUvf.jpg), well I just add them.
I have investigated and i found many examples but using maven and other things.

I can't change of IDE either.

Is it possible to use deeplearning4j on neatbeans without maven?

Greeting!

Comment: If you're doing anything java related, you should have access to maven. It's ubiquitous across the industry as a build tool. I would work instead on either A. making the case to your boss that you need maven on your workstation (and intellij or eclipse too!) if you're doing ANYTHING java related or B. you have an entirely unrelated job and you should probably be doing that work instead...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend building an uber jar separately with maven and then importing that in to your project.
You can do that on an external machine with the maven shade plugin.

The biggest problem we (as the deeplearning4j project) have with people trying to do this is they never seem to understand that there are transitive dependencies.
A big reason to use a build system is resolving dependencies.
Deeplearning4j is built to be a "pick what you need" library.
Unfortunately that also means complexity in the dependency management.

By default we assume people can use maven/sbt/gradle/lein etc - secondarily lobby your organization on adding a build tool to your work station. That will allow you to consume more libraries.

Comment: Thank for your advice, and you are right, I don't uderstand very well transitive dependencies, I'm doing an investigation about object detection, and I found dl4j, I read about a plugin of Maven on Neatbeans (this is the better option I have for now). 
I'll continue reading about that.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it, there is a Maven plugin in Netbeans, in Menu Tools > Plugins >  Available plugins > Search Maven, then you see a list like

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJJLd.jpg)

, I selected each one (five options), then restart IDE.
If you have a Maven proyect, you should have options to run them with Maven after that.